# Regex not getting all numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get the Name and Numbers from a string that looks like:

```
string = '><span>Name</span></p><div class="info"><span>100 years old<'
```

The thing is that the following pattern is not getting all numbers:

```
re.findall('<span>([a-zA-Z]+)</span>(.*)([0-9]+)',string)
```

Instead it returns the last numbers from the group of numbers (from the example above '0')

```
[('Name','</p><div class="info"><span>10','0')]
```

I want it to return `[('Name','</p><div class="info"><span>','100')]`

---

I know that I can do the following to get it working.

```
re.findall('<span>([a-zA-Z]+)</span>(.*)>([0-9]+)',string)
```

---

But, why is the first regex not getting all numbers?

Comment: What, [again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/395321)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is [greedy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) by default - changing that selector to `.*?` results in a non-greedy matcher:

```
>>> re.findall('<span>([a-zA-Z]+)</span>(.*?)([0-9]+)',string)
[('Name', '</p><div class="info"><span>', '100')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the "." is getting some of the numbers.

You can try this instread

"([a-zA-Z]+)(\\D*)([\\d]+)"

NOTE : I do not know if you need to escape "\".